# VB.net extracting values from text file

Tags: vb.net

I have a text file named `range.txt` with the following contents:

> MTN_G_ST_TT:i=67:a=89

I need to get the value `67` into a variable called `gbl_min` and `89` into a variable called `gbl_max`.

Comment: And?  What have you tried? What do you know about this data? Will it always be `i=` and `a=`, or could there be other values? What about the MTN_G_ST_TT part? How can that vary? Can there be additional sections? Can the values ever contain decimal points, negative signs or other numeric artifacts? What about white space? The rule of thumb here and anywhere is you should expect as much effort in the answers you get as you put into the question you asked.

Answer (score 4):

While the information in the question is woefully inadequate, here is an attempt:

```
Dim data As String = File.ReadAllText("range.txt") 'MTN_G_ST_TT:i=67:a=89
Dim results = Regex.Matches("[ai]=([0-9]+)(:|$)", data)
gbl_min = Integer.Parse(results.Item(0).Groups(1).Value)
gbl_max = Integer.Parse(results.Item(1).Groups(1).Value)
```

Answer (score 2):

You read and split text:

```
 Using sr As New IO.StreamReader("C:\\tmp\range.txt")
            Dim strLineData As String = sr.ReadLine()
            Dim oArr = strLineData.Split(":")
            If oArr.Length = 3 Then
                Dim gbl_min = oArr(1).Replace("i=", "")
                Dim gbl_max = oArr(2).Replace("a=", "")
            End If
        End Using
```